# What makes the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality so important?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is $(a\cdot b)^2 \leq |a|^2|b|^2$.  Why is this considered such an important inequality: to quote my textbook it's "one of the most important inequalities in all of mathematics".  But why?  Doesn't it just immediately follow from the definition of the dot product: $a\cdot b = |a||b|\cos(\theta)$?  And even if you define the dot product differently, like maybe $a\cdot b = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 +...$, it still doesn't seem all THAT important to me.  So what makes this particular inequality so important/ interesting?

Comment: For one, it essentially helps to generalize the triangle inequality that is so often used in analysis.  Also, in dealing with statistics, it can be used to show that the linear correlation between two random variables is between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Inequalities (including this one) are important in analysis, as they help bound things.

Comment: OK.  I guess I'll just have to wait until I get to real analysis to see where this inequality comes in handy.

Comment: The notion of the dot product (or generally, any inner product) is more general than any reasonable notion of an "angle" that you might have.  The fact that $a \cdot b = |a||b| \cos \theta$ is **not** a definition.  The definition is $a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots$, and the cosine formula follows (in $3$ dimensions or fewer) from the law of cosines.

Comment: There are some pretty good answers given [here](http://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality-considered-to-be-one-of-the-most-important-inequalities-in-mathematics).

Comment: Why does the cosine formula only work in 3 dimensions or fewer?  Can't we always consider a and b to be in some plane subspace of n-dimensional space?

Comment: Perhaps you can argue that this works in $n$-dimensional space; though as far as I'm concerned my notions of Euclidean geometry go out the window.  The subplane/law of cosines argument certainly fails, however, in infinite dimensional space, which is where the more interesting consequences of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality come into play.

Comment: One possible answer is your book is being overly dramatic.

Comment: Easy to prove $\not \Rightarrow$ unimportant.

Comment: You don't have to wait for analysis; this inequality is already important in Euclidean geometry.  For example, it says that the tangent (hyper)plane to a sphere is perpendicular to the radius.  If you're trying to reconstruct Euclidean geometry in $\mathbb R^n$ (even $n=2$, $n=3$) using the tools that are most natural in that setting — everything in coordinates, not synthetic methods — this inequality is crucial.  (And yes, you're completely right that it involves only the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$, whatever the dimension of the ambient space.)

Answer (score 6):

The triangle inequality is an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The triangle inequality is very important, especially since it is a condition for metric spaces. It is also very useful in probability theory with regards to the variance of $Y$ where $Y$ is a random variable. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality also is important because it connects the notion of an inner product with the notion of length.

Answer (score 3):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds for much wider range of settings than just the two- or three-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$.

In fact, it holds for all kind of spaces, where an inner product (an abstract concept) is defined. Thus it can be applied to bound things in wide number of settigns.

Comment: My thesis advisor used to say that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and integration by parts is all you need to do analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Those questions are rather hard to answer. An answer "The property $A$ is very important, because it can be used to prove properties $B$, $C$ and $D$ that are very important" does not clarify much but rise more questions why the latter are important. A definition of an "important result", that is the easiest to grasp by a non-professional, may come from a statistical estimation: if we count all known results (theorems etc) in analysis to be $N$, and let $M$ be the number of those that use a particular result, e.g. the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, in their simplest proof (i.e. it would be much harder to prove without it), then $\frac{M}{N}$ may serve as a measure of importance. This kind of statistics is, of course, never calculated explicitly, but rather understood intuitively by an individuum who has a background in a certain subject, and others have to trust him until they accumulate their own statistical data.

Those who say that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is important may refer to that the ratio $\frac{M}{N}$ for this result is relatively high compared to the average. However, one can argue that the inequality $x^2\ge 0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ is much more important in this sense.

An alternative (*qualitative* instead of *quantitative*) way to measure importance is perhaps to judge the influence of a particular notion and possibility to generalize it to other, more general constructions, that helps to study those. In this sense, the CS inequality is as important as the notion of a *norm* which was generalized from the plane and the $3D$ space to $\mathbb{R}^n$ first, and then to an abstract vector space, giving rise to Hilbert spaces, Banach spaces and a huge and very successful area of mathematics called *functional analysis*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with
$$
a\cdot b = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 +...
$$
it is just Cauchy's inequality.  Then there is one with integrals, Buniakovskii's inequality.  Finally one with abstract inner products, Schwarz' inequality. All of them are important.

For example, to find many applications, consult the classic book *Inequalities* by Hardy, Littlewood & Polya.